# Make program repeat (more then on entry)

Tags: java

How do I get it to loop to see if they have more then one word to translate? I think that I'm on the right track to have it repeat, have to just be missing a small detail I can't see.

Thanks!

So here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class holdingCode
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

        System.out.println("Please enter a word to be translated: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



        //Grabs a word for the user to translate further down

    String answer = "";        
   do
   { 
        String newWord = in.nextLine();
        newWord = newWord.toUpperCase(); 

      char vowel = Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(0));

      if (vowel == 'a' || vowel == 'e' || vowel == 'i' || vowel == 'o' || vowel == 'u')
      {
         String pigLatinWay = newWord + "WAY";
         System.out.println("Your word in pig latin is " + pigLatinWay + ".");
         System.out.println("Do you have another word to translate? (Y/N)");
         answer = in.nextLine();  
         //converts if it is a vowel
       }//end of if code   

       else 
       {
          if (true)
          {
             String first = newWord.substring(0,1);
             String slice = newWord.substring(1,newWord.length());
             System.out.println(" Your translated word is " + slice + first + "AY"); 
             System.out.println("Do you have another word to translate? (Y/N)");
             answer = in.nextLine();             
             //converts if it isn't a vowel
          }//end of if code
        }//end of else code

    }

    while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    }//end of pigLatin


}//end of program
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `String anwser = in.nextLine();` is restricted to the blocks that it is defined in

so try

after

```
newWord = newWord.toUpperCase();
String answer = "";
```

in block

```
anwser = in.nextLine();
```

and finally your comparison

```
while (anwser.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

**edit**

To summarize you can do

```
  String answer;

    do 
    {
        String newWord = in.nextLine();
        newWord = newWord.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: So I tried that I get "holdingCode.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
         anwser = in.nextLine(); "

Comment: are you sure that you declared `answer` as per my answer?

Comment: I put the "String anwser = ""; right below the same spot you have it like below the all upper case. then changed it from String answer to just anwser= in.nextLine();

Comment: anwser = in.nextLine();

Comment: check your spelling `answer` not `anwser`

Comment: Ok your right that worked. So now when I run it, it has to enter a Y or a N. If I put a N i ends. If I type a Yes it ask the question again. How do I make it loop again back to translate a word? Thanks again for helping!

Comment: So I'm guessing your post before told me how to fix the error asking me to anwser Y or N again. but waht does CR-LF mean?

Comment: Ok thanks for being patient with me still learning. So check my code now and see what you think. When I do y, now I get a another error :(  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at holdingCode.main(holdingCode.java:21)

Comment: works fine for me.  What is your input?  Do you push ENTER after entering Y ?

Comment: Yes I did. So I see what is happening. After enter yes then enter. How can I make it ask the user to input another word? If I enter just the word it works, but want to have it say something like : please enter another word:

Comment: go on, you can do it - try.  Where do you think you would like to see this?  Just before the input is read?

Comment: Ok sweet got it to work :) Your seriously the best! Ok one more question if you can help. So I am suppose to move the constant cluster if possible. So I need to identify my first vowel which can be done with a char. Then I can get the position with a substring. So I believe I have all the code to also do that. I just need to make the char instead of 0 make it a variable like a i right? Then change the substring rules on else if statement.

Comment: You can get the index using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)